# Выполнить скрипт если виден элемент jQuery

Tags: jquery

Мне нужно выполнять скрипт один раз как только указанный блок будет в видимости экрана... Как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста? Желательно примером

Answer (score 1):

Определить видно ли элемент на экране или нет, можно проанализировав положение верхней границы и положение скроллбара окна

При изменение положения скроллбара окна возникает событие `$(window).scroll()`

Определить впервые показывается элемент или нет, можно при помощи какого-нибудь глобального флага

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var cont = $('.content');
    if (!cont.hasClass('visible')) {
      var wh = $(this).height();
      var topOffset = cont.offset().top - $(this).scrollTop();
      var visible = (topOffset <= wh) && (topOffset + cont.height() > 0);
      if (visible) {
        cont.addClass('visible');
        console.log('Visible!!!');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.padding {
  height: 300px;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="padding">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="padding">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но скрипт выполняется каждый раз при скроле... А мне нужно чтобы он выполнялся только один раз.

Comment: Один раз выполнится `console.log('Visible!!!')`